# How to unset PHP session variable inside jQuery if condition?

Tags: php, jquery

I was trying to unset a php session variable inside a jQuery if block. Whenever someone unchecks a checkbox it should unset a specific session variable. Here is my code below

**PHP**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myName'] = "John";
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"> Check to set session
</form>
```

**jQuery** :

```
$('form').change(function(){
    if($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')){

        // Some statements here

    }else{
        <?php unset($_SESSION['myName']); ?>
    }
});
```

But the code is not working here. It is not unsetting the php session variable. Please provide me a solution. Thanks.

Note : I can do it by using AJAX by loading the php code from another page. But I want it to be done by using jQuery only.

Or is there any solution in jQuery that I can unset session variable without using PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work this way.

All PHP codes are executed before Javascript function .
To achieve this :

- You have to do AJAX or form submission.

You just cant do it by only jQuery.

Comment: Is there any code in jQuery to unset session variable?

Comment: @AnjanTalukdar JavaScript runs on browser, while php on server. Session is handled server side. You cannot affect session variables via JavaScript. You can only make an Ajax request to the server that can actually affect session variables.

Comment: Yeah ! I understand. I did that.